# how to block presses around child view controller using swift 4.0?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

i'm attaching a child view controller to my view :

```
func showRaitingDialog () {

        let popupRateExpiriance = UIStoryboard (name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ratePopupId") as! RateViewController

        //adding the popup view to the corrent view controller
        print ("this happens after")
        self.addChildViewController(popupRateExpiriance)

        popupRateExpiriance.refrenceToController = self

        popupRateExpiriance.view.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.addSubview(popupRateExpiriance.view)
        popupRateExpiriance.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    }
```

that child view controller is actually just a costume dialog that i did in my app.

my question is how do i block the presses around this dialog ? (so far the user can press on the screen blow it if he presses around the view controller itself)

Comment: Simple way is to put a transparent view, filling all screen, inside your RateViewController. Touching it does not permit user to touch "under" (through it). Second way is to identify point of touch and see if is inside your RateViewController frame. But use first, is simple than this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build a custom component and introduce the padding between the newly build child and your current one.

```
  @IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        showRaitingDialog ()
    }

    func showRaitingDialog () {
        let popupRateExpiriance = UIStoryboard (name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ratePopupId") as! RateViewController

        //adding the popup view to the corrent view controller
        addChild(popupRateExpiriance)

//        popupRateExpiriance.refrenceToController = self // << maybe you should create an interface / delegate

        popupRateExpiriance.view.frame = self.view.frame
        view.addSubview(popupRateExpiriance.view)
        popupRateExpiriance.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
```

The controller on the right has the background view colour set to clear.

[image]

Here is the result at runtime after the button has been pressed to display the child controller (the user can no longer press the button).

[image]

Comment: Updated, please recheck